# how to uninstall eclipse fully on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed on my ubuntu 21.04 eclipse indigo. but I forgot I how to install it, using apt-get or rpm or other ways install.

when today I install some update for it, the eclipse appear some bugs ,for example, it can not find editor, ther ADT can not appear.

So I want to uninstall it.

I use sudo apt=get remove eclipse, then it is OK.

but when I input in cmd line: eclipse.
there still have eclipse appear.

So I ask how to fully the installed

eclipse on ubuntu

thanks

Comment: close adb task in System Monitor after try this!

Comment: I close adb process in SM. but when I use sudo aot-get remove eclipse. It tell me the eclipse package  is not installed, 0 is unisntalled.     but after that when I input ecipse in cmd line. still the eclipse will appear.

Comment: restart device after try...

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is based on Debian and therefore uses .deb packages usually managed by apt-get. Hence you can be pretty sure rpm is not involved.

Either you installed it via apt-get or you manually installed it somewhere.
Check `type eclipse` to find out where it lives. If you suspect a file might come from some package you can use `dpkg -S filename` to check which package includes this file.

If you simply want to install another fresh eclipse you can just download it from the website extract it to a new folder and use this. - Any other (possible broken) installations should be pretty independent of this.

Comment: I "type eclipse" and get a remind: eclipse is hashed(/usr/bin/eclipse).

Comment: Now check with `dpkg -S /usr/bin/eclipse` what package it belongs to. If it does not belong to any package check with `ls -l /usr/bin/eclipse`. Maybe it is just a symlink to some local file.

Comment: input: dpkg -S /usr/bin/eclipse  output: eclipse-platform:/usr/bin/eclipse input: ls -l /usr/bin/eclipse output: -rwxr -xr -x 1 root root 1160 Apr 4 2012 /usr/bin/eclipse              How should I do next?

Comment: the first line tells you that there is a package `eclipse-platform` which installed the binary. Once you remove the package the binary will be gone, too. You can also check with `aptitude search eclipse` what other eclipse packages your system knows about. Those starting with a "i" are currently installed.

Comment: yes。thanks very much. with i is now installed, mean that if I want to del them thoroughly I can del these i ones. and with p starting is what mean?

Comment: p is for "purged", i.e. "not installed". - There is also a man page explaining such things... ;)

Comment: Thanks, michas - no idea why this question is marked as off topic, but your answer at 13:33 was the solution.